# Recyclerview grid layout manager that fills one column first

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I would like a recyclerview layout manager that works like a GridlayoutManager with two columns but fills the first column first before it adds items to the 2nd column. Or rather adds the remaining items to the second column.
Any suggestions?

Comment: your question is not very clear, I can't picture what layouting you're planning. Maybe if you could add a drawing? PS.: Did you check the `SpanSizeLookup`?

Comment: @Budius. If there are 10 items, 1-5 should go into column 1, then 6-10 go into column 2. I hope that is clear

Comment: It means that your grid-recyclerview should have a fixed height?? It doesn't make sense in respect to RecyclerView. If you want your items are selectively arranged inside your grid, an easy way is to organize them into 2 sub arrays and update them respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct layout manager that will do that for you **BUT**, I guess it's better, easier, more rational to re-order the List or whatever data structure is filling the adapter than trying to mess with the layout manager.

An example of how to do that would be during `bindView`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder (VH holder, int position) {
    position = translatePosition(position);
    // then carry on with your normal bind code
}
```

then create this method `translatePosition` with some simple math that will re-order stuff the way you want/need.